# DataFrame transformation in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have next DataFrame in R:

```
col1 col2 col3
a    W    1
a    Q    1
b    T    2
b    W    3
b    Q    1
b    Z    2
c    T    3
c    Z    1
....
```

I want to transform it in the next Data Frame

```
col1 T W Q Z
a    0 1 1 0
b    2 3 1 2
c    3 0 0 1
...
```

What is the most efficient way to do it in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
reshape(df,dir='w',idvar='col1',timevar='col2');
##   col1 col3.W col3.Q col3.T col3.Z
## 1    a      1      1     NA     NA
## 3    b      3      1      2      2
## 7    c     NA     NA      3      1
```

---

If we want to match the expected output exactly (except for column order which doesn't appear to have a pattern AFAICT):

```
res <- reshape(df,dir='w',idvar='col1',timevar='col2');
names(res)[-1L] <- sub('.*\\.','',names(res)[-1L]);
res[is.na(res)] <- 0L;
rownames(res) <- NULL;
res;
##   col1 W Q T Z
## 1    a 1 1 0 0
## 2    b 3 1 2 2
## 3    c 0 0 3 1
```

Comment: @ bgoldist, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `dcast` from `data.table` to convert to 'wide' format.

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), col1~col2, value.var='col3', fill = 0)
#   col1 Q T W Z
#1:    a 1 0 1 0
#2:    b 1 2 3 2
#3:    c 0 3 0 1
```

---

Or another option is `spread`

```
library(tidyr)
spread(df1, col2, col3, fill=0)    
#  col1 Q T W Z
#1    a 1 0 1 0
#2    b 1 2 3 2
#3    c 0 3 0 1
```

Comment: why did you reopen? it is a clear dupe imo

Comment: the question was about efficient transform so i thought if the other answer get selected it may confuse readers

Comment: just leaving a comment telling OP to use `data.table` or `tidyr` would have been enough, still no need to reopen imo

Comment: that is a good option, didn't thought about it

Comment: could you close it again then?